# Better understand debounceTime (RXJS) for an API request

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to create a search engine (input) where each time a user starts typing, it'll wait a bit before sending a query call. From my understanding, we would import

```
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { debounceTime } from "rxjs/operators";
```

The purpose of using `of` is because we will be using a string. As for `debounceTime`, we want to only process (make a request) to the last input that has been written in the set amount of time we pick. For this implementation, the way I have it set is

```
const PostTypeSelection = ({ client }) => {
  const [search, updateSearch] = useState("");
  const [tags, updateTags] = useState([]);
  const searchObserver = of(search);

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    updateSearch(value);
    searchObserver
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(1000),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(x => console.log("we run query here", x));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Select tags you'll want to see</p>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="search"
        placeholder="Type tag name"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      {tags.map(tag => {
        return (
          <div key={tag.id}>
            {tag.name} ({tag.count})
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

My main question is what is wrong with my implementation? There is no delay when I start typing and the `console.log` get run immediately. Another problem I noticed is if I tried to use `delay`, it doesn't remove previous request just sends them all after a set amount of time.

All help is appreciated especially in better understanding how to use an `Observer` and better understand the right use of `debounceTime`

Comment: What you probably want is the rxjs operator `fromEvent()`, see the docs [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/fromEvent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take what I am going to say with a grain of salt. I am not a Rxjs developer (being honest I have never used the lib ) but I get the concepts.

I see two problems in you implementation:

1. For every keypress you are creating and new observer and subscripting to it, because all the pipe and subscribe code is in the handler.
2. From what the documentation says about `of`, it emits the provided values in a sequence. For example: `of(1,2,3,3)`. Here I don't think you have a sequence. Every time you update the state the whole function runs resulting in `of` begin called once with every value: `of('a')`, `of('ab')`, `of('abc')`, not `of('a', 'ab', 'abc')`.

This is what I did to make it work:

```
const PostTypeSelection = ({ client }) => {
  const [tags, updateTags] = useState([]);
  const searchObserver = new Subject().pipe(
    debounceTime(1000),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );
  searchObserver.subscribe(x => console.log("we run query here", x))
  const handleChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    searchObserver.next(value)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Select tags you'll want to see</p>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="search"
        placeholder="Type tag name"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      {tags.map(tag => {
        return (
          <div key={tag.id}>
            {tag.name} ({tag.count})
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```